# Did Locke think that animals have innate knowledge?

Tags: epistemology, knowledge, locke

Locke famously believed that humans were born as a tabula rasa. Did he also think the animals are blank slates?

Comment: See [Essay](https://www.earlymoderntexts.com/assets/pdfs/locke1690book2.pdf), II.11.11: "It has often been thought that the crucial difference is that men alone can reason, but that isn’t right. For if lower animals have any ideas at all and aren’t bare machines (as some think they are), we can’t deny that they have some reason. It seems to me as obvious that some of them sometimes reason as that they have sense;
but when they reason it is only with particular ideas, just as they received them from their senses and not subjected to abstraction."